# SmtpClient and app.config system.net configuration

Tags: c#, .net, email, app-config

I'm having an issue with a .NET 3.5 library I'm developing to send emails.
I put the `system.net` configuration into `app.config`:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="mail@domain.com">
      <network host="myserver.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And I instantiate the SmtpClient without params:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

But the configuration is not read (I'm trying to test the library with NUnit) and I get a `System.InvalidOperationException`, because the configuration is not read and thus the host is null.

Shouldn't the configuration be read automatically?

Comment: Had a similar problem over 2 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737946/net-configuration-section-designer-where-is-my-collection/738501#738501

Comment: Thank you John. I had just came to the same conclusion... ;) I should have thought more about it definitely!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you add your configuration block (as shown above) to the {appName}.exe.config or web.config - the configuration for the class library is taken from one of those files at runtime, not from the app.config of the class library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Davide. It is a class library and I'm trying to test it with NUnit (does it make any difference?), anyway the section is present in the .config file so I'm still stuck...

Comment: you are the most welcome, I gave similar answer to same question some weeks ago, it's a common error I also did in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized I'm definitely doing it the wrong way (there's also [a similar post from John about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737946/net-configuration-section-designer-where-is-my-collection/738501#738501) and the solution is there...).

The mailsettings is available only at the application level, so the test project should know about your settings to take them into account.

Thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44765/john-rasch) and [Davide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559144/davide-piras) for pointing me to the right direction!